# How to let users discover sites they don't have access to?

Tags: best-practices, directory

What is the best way to make users aware of existing sites (they don't have access to)?

We have this scenario: In our organisation everybody is allowed to create team sites for ad hoc collaboration. But this leads to the problem that multiple sites may be created for the same purpose. How do I let users discover already existing sites? If users are aware of the existence of a team/collaborationgroup they can request access, instead of creating a new one.

For instance three departments may be thinking about organizing a 'secret santa'-type of event. Now we end up with 3 secret santa team sites. I rather have them team up.

Comment: What tools you have access to / feel comfortable using?

Comment: Anything goes. As simple as Configuring OOB components or as complex as Custom (C#) Solutions.

Comment: Security trimming is nice, but for discovering content you might be interessed in but don't (yet) have access to, it is a hurdle.

Comment: Yepp! What crosses my mind is some sort of simple webpart that does a search, but in an elevated context. That would allow you to search and list sites that not all users have access to.